# Declaration for an array being called into main from a method (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I am fairly new to java, and am having what I assume is a simple problem with my program.

For the method `arrayTest2`, I cannot import it into main due to an error on compilation:

```
"Cannot find symbol, symbol: variable dataStorage".
```

I have tried also tried the declarations:

```
arrayTest2(dataStorage[][])
```

and

```
arrayTest2(dataStorage[5][5])`
```

but they don't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

```
import io.*;

public class TrialArray
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        arrayTest();
        arrayTest2(dataStorage);
    }

    public static void arrayTest()
    {
        int[][] dataStorage = new int[5][5];

        dataStorage[1][2] = 1;

        System.out.printf("THIS PART WORKS");
    }

    public static void arrayTest2(int[][] dataStorage)
    {
        dataStorage[2][2] = 3;

        System.out.printf("THIS DOESNT");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is the scope: Something defined in one function is not visible in another. What you will normally do to solve this is to return the value. Something like this:

```
import io.*;

public class TrialArray
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int[][] dataStorage = arrayTest();
        arrayTest2(dataStorage);
    }

    public static int[][] arrayTest()
    {
        int[][] dataStorage = new int[5][5];

        dataStorage[1][2] = 1;

        System.out.printf("THIS PART WORKS");

        return dataStorage;
    }

    public static void arrayTest2(int[][] dataStorage)
    {
        dataStorage[2][2] = 3;

        System.out.printf("THIS DOESNT");
    }

}
```

Alternatively you could have your `dataStorage` field as a global variable, this is however potentially very confusing. To do that you'd define

```
public class TrialArray
{
    private static int[][] dataStorage;

    // ...

    public static void arrayTest() {
        dataStorage = new int[5][5];

        dataStorage[1][2] = 1;

        System.out.printf("THIS PART WORKS");
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to pass `dataStorage` to your `arrayTest`-function, but `dataStorage` is not a field of the class, neither is it a local variable of `main` (aka `dataStorage` does not exist in `main`).

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    arrayTest();
    arrayTest2(dataStorage); //<------- What is dataStorage?
}
```

[Here is a little tutorial on variable scopes in Java](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/local.html). You probably want to return the array you created in `arrayTest()` and use it, but I am just guessing what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

on this line

```
arrayTest2(dataStorage);
```

You are passing parameter to method, that has one argument "dataStorage", but you don't declare it.

Answer (score -1):

You cant access variables in declared inside other methods.

To make it work, you would have to do this:

```
public class TrialArray
{
    int[][] dataStorage;

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        dataStorage = new int[5][5];
        arrayTest();
        arrayTest2(dataStorage);
    }

    public static void arrayTest()
    {

        dataStorage[1][2] = 1;

        System.out.printf("THIS PART WORKS");
    }

    public static void arrayTest2(int[][] dataStorage)
    {
        dataStorage[2][2] = 3;

        System.out.printf("THIS DOESNT");
    }
}
```